# How to insert a new row in DB using RIA in code behind without DataForm?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have all of the data in the code below defined in XAML:

```
    <dds:DomainDataSource x:Name="ddsContAttachment" QueryName="GetMContAttachment" AutoLoad="True" LoadSize="20">
        <dds:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <employee:ContractSrv />
        </dds:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <dds:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
            <filter:SortDescriptor PropertyPath="wContId" Direction="Ascending" />
            <filter:SortDescriptor PropertyPath="wSeqId" Direction="Ascending" />
        </dds:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
    </dds:DomainDataSource>
```

How do I insert a DB row without filing DataForm in the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code-behind, you should be able to do the following:

```
// get a new entity
var attachment = new Attachment();

// initialize attachment properties as needed
this.ddsContAttachment.DataView.Add(attachment);

// when ready to submit the new record...
this.ddsContAttachment.SubmitChanges();
```